# multiple CAKeyframeAnimation in different layers at the same time

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-animation

Does anyone now how can I animate multiple layers at the same time using CAKeyframeAnimation ?
Each layer has its own CAKeyframeAnimation object. Take a look at the code below:

I have a method that receives an object, creates the CAKeyframeAnimation and attaches the animation to it:

```
- (void)animateMovingObject:(CALayer*)obj
               fromPosition:(CGPoint)startPosition
                 toPosition:(CGPoint)endPosition
                   duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    //pathAnimation.fillMode = kkCAFillModeRemoved; // default 
    //pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES; // default
    pathAnimation.duration = duration;

    // create an empty mutable path
    CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    // set the starting point of the path
    CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, startPosition.x, startPosition.y);

    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 
                          startPosition.x, endPosition.y, 
                          startPosition.x, endPosition.y,
                          endPosition.x, endPosition.y);
    pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
    [obj addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"pathAnimation"];
    CGPathRelease(curvedPath);
}
```

Now, suppose I have 3 layers added as a sublayer in my board game and I make the following calls:

```
CALayer obj1 = ... // set up layer and add as sublayer
[self animateMovingObject:obj1
             fromPosition:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
               toPosition:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)
                 duration:2.0];

CALayer obj2 = ... // set up layer and add as sublayer
[self animateMovingObject:obj2
             fromPosition:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
               toPosition:CGPointMake(150.0, 100.0)
                 duration:2.0];

CALayer obj3 = ... // set up layer and add as sublayer
[self animateMovingObject:obj3
             fromPosition:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
               toPosition:CGPointMake(200.0, 100.0)
                 duration:2.0];
```

By doing this, I can see only the `obj3` being moved from position (0.0, 0.0) to (200.0, 100.0).
What am I missing? Should I use NSOperationQueue/Threads?
Using the `animationDidStart:` delegate method of the CAKeyframeAnimation doesn't seem to be  useful in this context.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to group a series of animations like this, so that they are guaranteed to be synchronized, you could wrap them in a CATransaction:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];     

// Do animations

[CATransaction commit];
```

However, I'm not quite sure why the code you've written doesn't fire off the correct animations for each layer, even if they weren't synchronized.

Note that by setting `removedOnCompletion` to YES, your animation will run and then the object will hop back to its starting point at the end.  You probably want that to be NO.

Comment: Thanks for answering Brad. Although the start/end position of the animation are not my problem, you made nice observations. In my case I had removedOnCompletion = YES redundantly (it is the default). My steps regarding this are: 1) set the layer position to it's final position; 2) calculate the starting/ending position of the animation separately (in which the animation's ending position is the current layer position). I also left 'fillMode' to its default (kCAFillModeRemoved). My problem is not the position of the layers during/after the animations, it has to do with sequential animations.

Comment: If I set the delegate property of the three animations, I notice in the 'animationDidStop:finished:' delegate callback that the first 2 animations call this method with the argument 'finished = NO', and the last one (which corresponds to the layer that I see being animated) get's 'finished = YES'. This makes sense to what I see, but I wonder what is stoping my animations. I'm not calling any 'stop' method in my code, I'm just calling the 'animateMovingObject:..' methods three times sequentially. Thanks

Comment: I edit my question with the "upgrades", although the problem still occurs.

Comment: Please look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410969/the-scope-of-a-catransaction-block

Comment: @Eduardo - Something else is going on here.  Those animations are almost behaving like they are being added to the same layer, where the first two are being canceled by the third with the same name.

Comment: The another link question I posted above explains what is happening: While the animation were being performed, I called in another part of the code the '[CATransaction flush]', which caused all the animations to be 'concluded immediately'. Thanks!

Comment: What would be the equivalent for Swift? It seems like `CATransition begin` is not available no more.