# The scope of a CATransaction block

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, core-animation

I have seen some code that removes a given layer from it's superlayer by doing the following:

```
void RemoveImmediately(CALayer *layer) {
    [CATransaction flush];
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                     forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

I have written a method that changes the position of a given layer in an animated way using CAKeyframeAnimation, which looks like this:

```
- (void)animateMovingObject:(NXUIObject*)obj
           fromPosition:(CGPoint)startPosition
             toPosition:(CGPoint)endPosition
               duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {    

    CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    pathAnimation.duration = duration;

    CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 
                      startPosition.x, endPosition.y, 
                      startPosition.x, endPosition.y,
                      endPosition.x, endPosition.y);
    pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
    [obj addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"pathAnimation"];
    CGPathRelease(curvedPath);
}
```

Up to know, everything is fine. Now suppose I have in my app a 'master layer', which has 3 sublayers. I want the first two sublayers to be moved to another position and the last one to be removed. So I did the following:

```
CALayer obj1 = ... // set up layer and add as sublayer
[self.masterLayer addSublayer:obj1];
[self animateMovingObject:obj1
             fromPosition:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
               toPosition:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)
                 duration:2.0];

CALayer obj2 = ... // set up layer and add as sublayer
[self.masterLayer addSublayer:obj2];
[self animateMovingObject:obj2
             fromPosition:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
               toPosition:CGPointMake(150.0, 100.0)
                 duration:2.0];

CALayer obj3 = ... // set up layer and add as sublayer
[self.masterLayer addSublayer:obj3];
// ...
RemoveImmediately(obj3);      // This removes the two previous animations too
//[obj3 removeFromSuperlayer];  // This just removes obj3, the previous animations works
```

Note that if I call `RemoveImmediately()`, even passing `obj3` as argument I can't see the first two layers being animated. However, if I remove the `obj3` just by calling `removeFromSuperlayer` the first two layers are animated normally.
Looks like the CATransaction block cancels all animations being done, even those that were created with CAKeyframeAnimation.

What I'm I missing?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of a CATransaction should just be between the `[CATransaction begin]` and `[CATransaction commit]` lines.

Also, you shouldn't need the `[CATransaction flush]` in that code.  Apple generally recommends you not force the execution of pending transactions for performance reasons, and the transaction you're setting up there should not affect any pending animations.

I'm guessing this odd behavior is still related to what you asked in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398111/multiple-cakeyframeanimation-in-different-layers-at-the-same-time), where the three animations are somehow interfering with one another.  As I commented there, this is behaving like the three animations are being added to one layer, not three independent ones.  I'd check and make sure there was no possibility of that happening (crossed pointers, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I showed me the way to get things done! The problem was the 'flush' method. I removed it and now I can see all animations running normally. The only thing that 'obj1', 'obj2' and 'obj3' have in common is that they are sublayers of 'masterLayer', so there weren't crossed pointers or any animation interfering in another. By calling the 'flush' method, the previous animations were stopped (the delegate method 'animationDidStop:finished:' finished argument returned NO, indicating that they were manually stopped (which I guess happened when the 'flush' method was called)).

Comment: Although it worked, I tried to understand what the documentation says about the flush method (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CATransaction/flush) and it still not clear for me why it cause my explicit animations to be 'stopped'.

Comment: @Eduardo - Yes, I've also had problems with `[CATransaction flush]` disrupting animations, because it interferes with the normal Core Animation rendering pipeline.  Only once have I needed it for something, and even then I found a way to redesign what I was doing to eventually remove that call.